# how to tell yum variables parser where the yum variable id starts and ends?

Tags: yum

Is there any way to tell the yum variables parser where the variable name starts and ends?

I'm having trouble embedding `$releasever`.

For example, this works:

```
# cat test.repo
[RHEL$releasever]
name=RHEL$releasever test
# yum  repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
repo id                   repo name         status                                                                                      
RHEL6                     RHEL6 test        0                                                                                           
repolist: 0
#
```

but this doesn't:

```
# cat test.repo
[RHEL$releasever_SOMETHING]
name=RHEL$releasever test
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Bad id for repo: RHEL$releasever_SOMETHING, byte = $ 4
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
repolist: 0
#
```

Alas, yum does not recognize `${releasever}` or `$(releasever)`  -- shell style and Make style.  Is there some other way to do it within yum?

Right now we have multiple yum repositories that are named like RHEL5_something and RHEL6_something and I want to consolidate that to RHEL$releasever_something as it would simplify our configuration management.

I can still consolidate the config by using a config mgmt variable rather than a yum variable; I just want to know if yum can do it?

Answer (score 5):

This is a [known issue](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2841281) which has been last updated by Red Hat on 4 January 2017 as of this writing.  The only workaround which I can suggest is to move SOMETHING to before your invocation of `$releasever`.